# Wikitable background bleeding

Tags: jquery, css, mediawiki

I am trying to create a table like this:

```
{| class="wikitable" style="background:#F00;"
|-
! colspan="3" | Title
|-  
! style="border-width:1px 0px; width:20px" | A
! style="border-width:1px 0px;" | [[A]]
! style="border-left-width:0px; width:20px" | A
|-
| colspan="3" | Text
|}
```

However, the red background "bleeds" to the right. i.e., to the right of the right border of the table, there is a vertical strip of red.

Upon closer inspection using Developer Tools, this is due to the paddings of the cells being set to 0.2em, and are (strangely) not rounded to integer pixels, giving a 2.54999px padding. The browser then renders the table box outside the right border.

This can be fixed by individually giving the cells a px-based padding. But this complicates the code so I am looking for a neater solution.

---

EDIT: Something also to note is that the "not rounded" behavior is caused by the "wikitable" class. I tried removing the class and the paddings ARE rounded.

EDIT2: Further experiments show that this is most likely because MediaWiki sets wikitables' paddings using jQuery's `.css()` method (or other equivalents, which does NOT round em-based measurements. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: What is your desired solution? Just one row with background red?

Comment: Yes. To be precise, I just don't want the bleeding. The table I am making uses the default gray background but with 5x these cells, giving a very visible bleed. I used red here to demonstrate the bleeding only

Comment: Ok, thx for responses, it will require some more thought... :)

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug. Can we have a screenshot or a live sample?

Answer (score 0):

if you use `table { border-spacing: 0; }`, the white space is gone. Tested on Chrome where `border-spacing` is initially set to `2px`.